# Is it possible to move a vent from the floor to the wall without ducts?

Tags: drywall, venting

my contractor needs to move the floor vent to the new closet wall.  His plan is to simply partially close off the floor vent, then build the closet wall over the remaining portion, allowing the air to just flow into the closet wall and out a vent which he will install about a foot off the ground.  He plans to block off the airflow about a foot off the ground with a 2x4 framed into the closet walls.  This does not seem like a good idea to me.  Doesnt he need to protect the drywall from moisture?  Or insulate the interior of the closet wall?

Comment: Welcome to the world of finding an HVAC contractor who doesn't both suck and blow.

Comment: Floor vent to what/where?  If it's a cold air return then this sounds fine -- it's done all the time.  If it's a warm air vent then he needs to be *very* careful to seal the wall space, so that no air escapes upward (and possibly into the attic).  In addition, there may be a code restriction on having a warm air vent routed this way without regulation ductwork.

Comment: Do not let that guy do it that way, if he seen it before the job was bid, and knew about it, he needs to be bound to do it the right way. Even if your work may not be inspected by a county official, to me all work is required to be done at least to code. Building codes are the minimum standard.

Comment: Are these vents (deliver conditioned air to the space), or returns (return room air to the HVAC equipment)?

Answer (score 5):

A vent isn't hard to extend.  Any decent contractor could extend your current vent to closet wall.  I am assuming this is the outside of the closet too - you don't ever put a vent in the inside of a closet and not even sure that is code.  Anyway you need to part ways with this contractor if you can. If he even thinks about telling you something that dumb then who knows what he is doing when you aren't watching.

Comment: Agreed, any contractor worth his salt can redo the ductwork and keep it to code. Same saying that if it is extended too far, it would affect the way that branch performs. If it is only a foot or two and/or only one elbow, it might do well anyway.

Answer (score 3):

According to this reference:

http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/community/forum/building-code-questions/27872/stud-spaces-air-ducts

using stud space as a *supply* duct is not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: this is a bad idea. Hire an AC contractor to re-do the vent, then your contractor can build a wall around it.